# Mongodb ssl certificate error in python, how can i fix the error?

Tags: python, mongodb, ssl

When i try to do actions on my shared mongodb i get this error while developing in python, how can i fix this ?

```
<ServerDescription ('cluster0xxxxmongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0xxxxmongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)')>
```

Comment: How about update cert?

Comment: how do i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install certifi

```
pip install certifi
```

Then use it in code:

```
import certifi
client = pymongo.MongoClient(f"mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.xxxxx.mongodb.net/db?retryWrites=true&w=majority",tlsCAFile=certifi.where())
```